# Spring - Unable to catch ConstraintViolationException when deleting an entity referenced in another table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, exception, transactional

I am trying to improve the way i handle exceptions coming from my DAO / service layers in my spring MVC app.  The method i use below works very nicely and does not cause a 500 error :

Controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/delete-{id}-strengthUnit"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String deleteStrengthUnit(@PathVariable String id) 
{
    StrengthUnit strengthUnit = strengthUnitService.findById(Integer.parseInt(id));

    try
    {
        strengthUnitService.delete(strengthUnit);

        session.setAttribute("successMessage", "Successfully deleted strength unit \"" + strengthUnit.getName() + "\"!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        session.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Strength unit \"" + strengthUnit.getName() + "\" is in use and cannot be deleted!");
    }

    return "redirect:/strengthUnits/list";
}
```

Service code

```
@Override
public void delete(StrengthUnit strengthUnit) throws ConstraintViolationException
{
    dao.delete(strengthUnit);
}
```

DAO code

```
@Override
public void delete(StrengthUnit strengthUnit) throws ConstraintViolationException
{
    super.delete(strengthUnit);
}
```

Master DAO code (all DAOs extend this abstract DAO class)

```
public void delete(T entity)
{
    getSession().delete(entity);
}
```

This code chain correctly intercepts the ConstraintViolationException (thrown by the DAO layer and forwarded to the controller by the service layer) and sets a variable in the session object with a nice message to present to the user in the next page.  All this works perfectly as it is now.

I am trying to improve my service layer so it can do all the exception catching and logging duties which result from interacting with the DAO layer.  I am trying to make this very simple change and i cannot for the life of me figure out why it is unable to catch the ConstraintViolationException when doing it as below :

Controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/delete-{id}-strengthUnit"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String deleteStrengthUnit(@PathVariable String id) 
{
    StrengthUnit strengthUnit = strengthUnitService.findById(Integer.parseInt(id));

    try
    {
        strengthUnitService.delete(strengthUnit);

        session.setAttribute("successMessage", "Successfully deleted strength unit \"" + strengthUnit.getName() + "\"!");
    }
    catch (EntityInUseException ex)
    {
        session.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Strength unit \"" + strengthUnit.getName() + "\" is in use and cannot be deleted!");
    }

    return "redirect:/strengthUnits/list";
}
```

Service code

```
@Override
public void delete(StrengthUnit strengthUnit) throws EntityInUseException
{
    try
    {
        dao.delete(strengthUnit);

        logEntryService.logDebug(LogEntry.SHARED, LogEntry.DATABASE, "Successfully deleted strength unit \"" + strengthUnit.getName() + "\"", logger);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logEntryService.logError(LogEntry.SHARED, LogEntry.DATABASE, "Error deleting strength unit \"" + strengthUnit.getName() + "\" : " + ex.getMessage(), logger);

        throw new EntityInUseException("Strength unit \"" + strengthUnit.getName() + "\" is in use and cannot be deleted!");
    }
}
```

The DAO code is completely unchanged.  With these simple changes, the controller should receive my custom exception but it does not.  The execution does not enter the catch block in the service layer even though things were working perfectly fine before the changes with no changes to the DAO layer.  Here is the exception i get when the code completely skips the catch block :

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FKlylli8qlwprfk1t59bx6krbk3". The conflict occurred in database "MDHIS", table "dbo.tblMed", column 'id_strenghUnit'.
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeBatch(JtdsStatement.java:1069)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:2544)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:118)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatch.java:104)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.execute(AbstractBatchImpl.java:147)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.executeBatch(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:212)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:633)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:478)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:356)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1454)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:511)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3278)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2474)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:178)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:39)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:271)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:98)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:609)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:532)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:304)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy107.delete(Unknown Source)
at com.mdenis.mdhis_webclient.controller.StrengthUnitController.deleteStrengthUnit(StrengthUnitController.java:155)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at com.mdenis.mdhis_webclient.filter.PermissionsFilter.doFilter(PermissionsFilter.java:125)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at com.mdenis.mdhis_webclient.filter.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:75)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:417)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I looked at another entity's delete operation (one that i didn't change yet) and the Exception is actually a DataIntegrityViolationException.  Even when setting my DAO to throw that exception, i am unable to have my service layer catch it.  The catch block is never reached and it prints a success message in the logs even though i get the 500 error and the above stacktrace immediately after.

Does this make sense to anyone?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get any kind of stacktrace when a `ConstraintViolationException` occurs? Also why have done your exception handling using try catch within the controller body itself and not delegated this over to an `ExceptionHandler` https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html

Comment: Does it print 'Error deleting strength unit' in log the files ?

Comment: Original post updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the question. Read the stack trace. I's not the delete() method which throws the exception. Because delete() simply consists in marking the entity for deletion in the persistence context. The actual deletion happens at flush time, when Hibernate actually executes the delete query, just before the commit. And since the service is transactional, the commit happens in the transactional proxy wrapping the actual service instance:

Flush:

```
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1454)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:511)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3278)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2474)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:473)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:178)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:39)
at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:271)
```

Called when Hibernate commits its transaction:

```
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:98)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:609)
```

because the Spring TransactionManager delagating to Hibernate commits

```
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:714)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:532)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:304)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
```

inside the proxy around the service

```
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy107.delete(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: That makes sense based on the stack trace indeed.  However, why is my old method working with a very similar approach and how can i make my new approach work?

Comment: Your old approach works because it encloses the call to the transactional proxy inside the try block. So it catches exceptions thrown by this proxy. You can make your new approach work by replacing it by the old one, which is the correct one: if you want to catch errors thrown by a transaction, the transaction must start and end inside the try block, not outside. Spring throws well-specified exceptions: just catch those rather than catching Exception.

Comment: This global exception handling, BTW, shouldn't be repeated everywhere. Spring has ControllerAdvice to deal with such exceptions in a central place.

Comment: I am trying to improve things gradually and global exception management is definitely the next thing i want to do.  Here is the weirdest part though.  I tried something slightly different with my VolumeUnit entity which is extremely similar in that it only has an id and a name property.  It uses the EXACT same code chain style as StrengthUnit.  My controller used to only catch Exception which i agree is terrible practice.  I found that the actual exception is of type DataIntegrityViolationException.  I therefore changed my DAO, Service and controller to catch this type and it works?!

Comment: Well, if you catch it in your controller, yes, it will work. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: I get what you mean now!  What if i marked my DAO class as transactional instead of the service?  That would allow the transaction to be contained within the service layer and allow me to work with the resulting exceptions, throwing my own right?

Comment: I can confirm that putting the Transactional annotation on the DAO instead of the service fixes the problem but i read in a lot of places that you normally want this annotation on the service.  So what i'm getting from all this is that you cannot catch an exception resulting from a Transactional method inside the method itself, which makes sense.  I'm relatively experienced with Spring but this stuff is pretty deep in the inner workings of Spring.  What i will likely do is stop trying to make a custom exception and just use what Spring throws instead.  Cheers